# prevent null value insert in parent table using OneToOne ralationship in spring hibernate

Tags: mysql, hibernate, spring-mvc

I have two table User and ProfilePic having OneToOne relationship bidirectional mapping. When uploading profile picture for User it create new User in database having null value. I need to prevent new user being inserted and want to insert value in ProfilePic table only.
please do not mark as duplicate or down-vote I am new to hibernate.
Here is related Code:

User Class:

```
    @Entity
@Table(name = "user_details")
public class User {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private int userId;
    private String firstName;
    private String lastName;
    private String gender;
    @Temporal(TemporalType.DATE)
    @DateTimeFormat(pattern = "yyyy-MM-dd")
    private Date dob;
    private String email;
    private String address;
    private String username;
    private String password;
    private String phoneNumber;
    private Boolean isActive;
    private String role;
    @OneToOne(mappedBy = "user")
    private ProfilePic profilePic;
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "user")
    private List<Login> login = new ArrayList<>();

-----getter setter---
}
```

PrfilePic Class:

```
@Entity
public class ProfilePic {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private int imageId;
    private String image_url;
    @OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinColumn(name = "userId", nullable = false)
    private User user;
---getter setter---
}
```

Repository class:

```
@Override
    public void saveProfilePic(ProfilePic profilePic) {
        HibernateUtil.getSession(sessionFactory).save(profilePic);
    }
```

Controller class:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/uploadProfileimage", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public String uploadProfileImage(@ModelAttribute User user, @ModelAttribute ProfilePic profilePic,
            @RequestParam("image") CommonsMultipartFile file, Model model) {
        String imageUrl = "";
        if (!file.getOriginalFilename().isEmpty()) {
            imageUrl = ImageUtil.writeImageToFile(file);
            profilePic.setImage_url(imageUrl);
            profilePic.setUser(user);
            pictures.add(profilePic);
            userService.saveProfilePic(profilePic);
        }
        return "redirect:/getProfile?userId=" + user.getUserId();
    }
```

log:

```
Hibernate: select next_val as id_val from hibernate_sequence for update
Hibernate: update hibernate_sequence set next_val= ? where next_val=?
Hibernate: select next_val as id_val from hibernate_sequence for update
Hibernate: update hibernate_sequence set next_val= ? where next_val=?
Hibernate: insert into user_details (address, dob, email, firstName, gender, isActive, lastName, password, phoneNumber, role, username, userId) values (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)
Hibernate: insert into ProfilePic (image_url, userId, imageId) values (?, ?, ?)
Hibernate: select user0_.userId as userId1_7_0_, user0_.address as address2_7_0_, user0_.dob as dob3_7_0_, user0_.email as email4_7_0_, user0_.firstName as firstNam5_7_0_, user0_.gender as gender6_7_0_, user0_.isActive as isActive7_7_0_, user0_.lastName as lastName8_7_0_, user0_.password as password9_7_0_, user0_.phoneNumber as phoneNu10_7_0_, user0_.role as role11_7_0_, user0_.username as usernam12_7_0_, profilepic1_.imageId as imageId1_6_1_, profilepic1_.image_url as image_ur2_6_1_, profilepic1_.userId as userId3_6_1_ from user_details user0_ left outer join ProfilePic profilepic1_ on user0_.userId=profilepic1_.userId where user0_.userId=?
```

Expected result : insert data only in ProfilePic table with associated user id
Actual result: data inserted in both table that is User and ProfilePic. New user created having null values in all column.
Help will be highly appreciated. I am stuck in it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The thing is, it's not a problem to insert data only in the ProfilePic if the user id is null, so no user is associated with this picture.

However if you want to insert data into ProfilePic WITH the user id, you also need to insert the associated user into the user table, otherwise the user id won't be available.

So, for example in MYSQL if you run this query:

```
INSERT INTO profile_pic (image_id, image_url, user_id) VALUES ('1', "/image", '1');
```

you will run into an error ( Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`stackoverflow`.`profile_pic`, CONSTRAINT `user_id` FOREIGN KEY (`user_id`) REFERENCES `user` (`user_id`))) 
So basically there is no user with id 1.

The solution is to use unidirectional mapping, in other words, user will reference profile_pic, but profile_pic won't.

You should change your model into something like:
User class:

```
    @Entity
    @Table(name = "user_details")
    public class User {
        @OneToOne
        private ProfilePic profilePic;
        // other fields, getters and setters
    }
```

ProfilePic class:

```
@Entity
public class ProfilePic {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private int imageId;
    private String image_url;
    // getters and setters
}
```

Then you'll be able to insert only into ProfilePic.
I hope this works for you!

Comment: Thank you @Agentk but I need to insert user id  to insure which profile picture belongs to which user which is only possible if there is user id present in profilePic table.